# Problem displaying query results in template

Tags: templates, go

I'm working on a page that will get a variable from the url, run a query against mysql db, fetch results and display them on the page. I'm using templates here.
I'm following some tutorial and got most of this done, however I'm stuck at one thing.

```
func dbConnection() (db *sql.DB) {
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
return db
}

type Order struct {
   Order_id int
   Customer string
   Date_of_purchase string
}
```

And here's my function that's supposed to get the data and render the template:

```
func CustomerPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
db := dbConnection()
//customer := r.URL.Query().Get("username")
query, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer='David'")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
order := Order{}
results := []Order{}
for query.Next(){
    var order_id int
    var customer, date_of_purchase string
    query.Scan(&order_id, &customer, &date_of_purchase)
    order.Order_id = order_id
    order.Customer = customer
    order.Date_of_purchase = date_of_purchase
    results = append(results, order)
    fmt.Println(order_id)
    fmt.Println(customer)
}
fmt.Println(results)
temp, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/orders.html")
temp.Execute(w, results)
defer query.Close()
}
```

And finally my template:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h3>Your username is {{ .Customer }}</h3>
{{ range . }}
<h2> {{ .Order_id }}</h2>
{{ end }}
```

With the prints I can see that the data is fetched correctly like this:

```
[{3485208 David 2019-06-03} {4448668 David 2019-03-10} {5727877 David 2019-08-23} {6979516 David 2019-03-04} {8277481 David 2019-02-07}]
```

The problem I'm having is displaying this data in the template. I get only the hard-coded text and no variables. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You're not checking the error returned by temp.Execute.

Comment: I checked it now and got this: template: orders.html:2:23: executing "orders.html" at <.Customer>: can't evaluate field Customer in type []main.Order

Comment: The way I understand this is I should be calling .Customer as defined in the struct?

Comment: "can't evaluate field Customer in type []main.Order" means just what it says. `.` has type `[]Order` and slices don't have fields, so `.Customer` is nonsensical. You forgot a `range` action or `index` call or something like that.